# How to check length of value having real datatype in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

How to check length of any value before its decimal point of real datatype in sybase.

means if value is 12345.6789 so it should provide output as 5. Let me know if anybody knows how to do it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str` function to trim the decimals `str (12345.6789)` returns `12346`

That value can then be used in the `char_length` function to determine the length.

I haven't gotten it to work combinining the two functions in one line (`char_length(str(12345.6789))`), so you may have to use a variable to keep the value between the two functions.